# invalid syntax in the code,which i think there should be no error

Tags: python

```
correct = [1 if ((a == 1 and b == 1) or (a == 0 and b == 0)) else 0 for (a, b)]
```

I am the newbie in the python world, and i find when i run my file,the program show

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

in the code above
but as i know,there should be no SyntaxError this code,so i want to ask why,where is wrong with this code?I had try to find where am i wrong,but still have no idea about this.
I use Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64 this version

Comment: What is a and b, please show the rest of the code. The syntax is invalid for sure.

Comment: you are missing an iterator

Comment: why are you using one liner if you are new in python first do it in simple way and your for loop is not completed try to do it in simple way first than use one liner

Comment: what is `else 0 for (a, b)` ?

Comment: May be you have a list of 2-tuples (say, `my_list`); you need `for a,b in my_list`. Or, you already have `a` and `b` defined; then you do not need the `for` part.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but you are missing an `in` statement or say iteration in your list comprehension.

```
my_list = [(1, 1), (1, 0)]
correct = [1 if ((a == 1 and b == 1) or (a == 0 and b == 0)) else 0 for (a, b) in my_list]
print(correct)
out: [1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is essentially "not xor", so, your whole logic can be replaced with 
`int(not (a ^ b))`:

```
a,b = 0, 0
print(int(not (a ^ b)))
a, b = 1, 0
print(int(not (a ^ b)))
a, b = 0, 1
print(int(not (a ^ b)))
a, b = 1, 1
print(int(not (a ^ b)))
#  1
#  0
#  0
#  1
```

If you don't like the "magical" "not xor" you can explicitly validate the input against `(0, 0)` and `(1, 1)`:

```
print(1 if (a, b) in ((0, 0), (1, 1)) else 0)
```

This replaces the `if` condition only. If you do have a list of tuples then you would still need the `in` as other answers suggest:

```
def validate(a, b):
    return int(not a ^ b)

li = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
print([validate(a, b) for a, b in li])
# [1, 0, 0, 1]
```

or with `map`, but then `validate` will need to be changed to accept a tuple (and a call to `list` is needed if using Python 3 and wanted output should be a list):

```
def validate(tup):
    return int(not tup[0] ^ tup[1])

li = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
print(list(map(validate, li)))
# [1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

After defining a and b, you could do something like this:

```
if (a==1 and b==1) or (a==0 and b==0):
    correct=1
else:
    correct=0
```

Or in ternary format, something like this:

```
correct=1 if ((a==1 and b==1) or (a==0 and b==0)) else 0
```

if what you want is to make correct=1 when (a=1 and b=1)  or (a=0 and b=0)   and make correct=0 for the rest of possibilities

Answer (score 0):

This is a gross misuse of a list comprehension.

The logic you may wish to implement *can* be implemented via a ternary statement:

```
a, b = 1, 1
correct = 1 if ((a == 1 and b == 1) or (a == 0 and b == 0)) else 0
#1
```

However, even this is close to unreadable. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with ternary statements; so I would advise splitting your logic:

```
test1 = (a == 1) and (b == 1)
test2 = (a == 0) and (b == 0)

correct = 1 if (test1 or test2) else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only have to evaluate `a` and `b` and you want a one-liner, you can go with

```
correct = 1 if ((a == 1 and b == 1) or (a == 0 and b == 0)) else 0
```

if `a` and `b` represent a couple of values in a list of tuples, and you want a list back of one and zeroes, you can use list comprehension:

```
correct = [1 if ((a == 1 and b == 1) or (a == 0 and b == 0)) else 0 for a,b in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
[whatever_expression for (a, b)]
```

is indeed incorrect - it should (from the purely syntaxic POV) be

```
[whatever_expression for (a, b) in some_iterable]
```

What you're really trying to do is quite unclear, but if you have two variables `a` and `b` and want to check if both are equal to `0` or both are equal to `1`, you don't need a list comprehension at all:

```
correct = 1 if (a == 0 and b == 0) or (a == 1 and b == 1) else 0
```

and since in Python, `Bool` is a subclass of `int` with `False == 0` and `True == 1`, this can be simplified to

```
correct = (a == 0 and b == 0) or (a == 1 and b == 1)
```

Using a list comprehension only makes sense if you actually have a list of pairs and want to test all those pairs, ie:

```
pairs = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
corrects = [(a == 0 and b == 0) or (a == 1 and b == 1) for (a, b) in pairs]
```

which would yield

```
[True, False, False, True]
```